# Laravel 5 register guard from service provider

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined a new guard which it's only difference from default "web" guard is provider's model.

So I registered it in config/auth.php:

```
'guards' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins'
    ],

],

'providers' => [

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Modules\AdminCore\Entities\Admin::class
    ]

]
```

It's working perfectly, but I need to define this guard in a laravel package.
I believe it's possible from my package's service provider, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `$this->mergeConfigFrom(...)` or overwritte a config/auth.php file from your package. Another way is using  `$this->app['config']->set($key, $array)`
Inside your service provider.